# Composite xrange in gnuplot

Tags: gnuplot

I have a periodic system and I want to fit some data for this system to a function, but I want to constrain to a range. Usually, if your range is from x_min to x_max this can be achieved with `fit [x_min:x_max] f(x) "data" via a,b,c,...`. However, because my system is periodic, I want to constrain to a range that contains a segment at the end of the array of x values and also at the beginning. That is, if x values are given within the interval [0:L], I want to include in the fit *both* `[0:x_max]` and `[x_min:L]`, where in this case x_max < x_min. How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
fit [min1:max2] f(x) "data" u 1:($1 <= max1 || $1 >= min2 ? $2 : 1/0) via a,b,c,...
```

That is, make use of the `[:]` for the outer range.

I'm not sure it's much *nicer* but it is a little bit shorter.

Alternatively, you could use `set table` in the following way:

```
set table 'newdata'
p [0:x_max] 'data'
p [x_min:L] 'data'
unset table

fit f(x) 'newdata' via a,b,c,...
```

Basically this writes a new file containing only the data between the two ranges. Arguably *nicer*, definitely not shorter!

Comment: Nice add up, and a bit shorter, but I think it is more complicated because now you need to mix the range operator and the conditional plot.

Comment: @Miguel I have suggested an alternative that you may prefer.

Comment: Variety is always good. I'll wait a bit for other possibilities, then accept this.

Answer (score 0):

I figured an ugly way to do it, but if anyone comes up with a nicer way I will accept that as the answer.

Imagine the two ranges where you want to fit (or plot) the data are given by `[min1:max1]` and `[min2:max2]`, then using a conditional fit and the "ignore" function `1/0` you can do the following:

```
fit f(x) "data" u 1:( ($1 >= min1 && $1 <= max1) || ($1 >= min2 && $1 <= max2) ? $2 : 1/0) via a,b,c,...
```

That is, if x is within the first interval or the second one, then use y as a value for the fit, otherwise ignore those data points.

This approach should also work with plot, but I think something like a composite range operator `[min1:max1 && min2:max2]` (which does *not* work) would be more desirable.